Change order of Limit and Integral pitfalls?
Probably it is a silly question. Say, we are given a function
$$
Y(\epsilon)=e^{\epsilon z}\left(\frac{z}{\epsilon}-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\right)
$$
to evaluate its limit as $\epsilon\to0$. I immediately thought that $Y(\epsilon\to0)=\infty$.
But later I found something must be wrong since $Y(\epsilon)$ is nothing else but
\begin{align}
I(\epsilon)=\int z^1 e^{\epsilon z}\mathrm{d}z&=\partial_\epsilon\int e^{\epsilon z}\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\partial_\epsilon\frac{e^{\epsilon z}}{\epsilon}\\
&=e^{\epsilon z}(\partial_\epsilon+z)\frac1\epsilon\\
&=e^{\epsilon z}\left(\frac{z}{\epsilon}-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\right)
\end{align}
where the integral constant is dropped off.
However if I evaluate the integrand first and then do integration, the expected result is easily reached $I(\epsilon\to0)=\frac12z^2$.
Then I checked backwards the integration process and realized if the lower and upper limits are given then take the limit process it becomes consistent, i.e.,
\begin{align}
I(\epsilon)&=\int_a^b z^1 e^{\epsilon z}\mathrm{d}z\\
&=e^{\epsilon z}\left.\left(\frac{z}{\epsilon}-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\right)\right|_a^b\\
&=\frac{e^{\epsilon a}-e^{\epsilon b}}{\epsilon^2}+\frac{be^{\epsilon b}-ae^{\epsilon a}}{\epsilon}
\end{align}
which as $\epsilon\to0$ becomes $\frac12(b^2-a^2)$ when L'hopital rule is applied.
Where is the pitfall trap when dealing with integral and limits?

You're forgetting about the $+C$ in the antiderivative. The original function and your limiting antiderivative are off by $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$. The lesson here is never take limits like that unless you provide bounds. Edit: From what you have written, what you actually have is $$I(\epsilon) = e^{\epsilon z}\left(\frac{z}{\epsilon}-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\right)+\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+C$$ and now taking the limit will result in the finite answer you are familiar with.
